# indexOf... How can I do this?

Tags: java, indexof

I'm trying to check if a string is equal to a value of a string array by using an integer using the indexOf method. Here's what I have:

```
public int[] COMPONENT_IDS = { 18, 22, 20, 10, 12, 14, 16 };
public String[] COMPONENT_STRINGS = { "pie", "chocolate bar", "donut", "baguette", "triangle sandwich", 
                                        "sandwich", "bread" };

public int[][] REWARDS = { {995, 5000000}, {12852, 625000}, {8851, 1250000} };

public void handleComponents(int c) {
    for(int i : COMPONENT_IDS) {
        if(i == c) {
            if(answer.equals(COMPONENT_STRINGS[COMPONENT_IDS.indexOf(i)]))
                sendReward();
            else
                sendPunishment();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
src\com\rs\game\player\content\AntiAFK.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                            if(answer.equals(COMPONENT_STRINGS[COMPONENT_IDS
.indexOf(i)]))
^
   symbol:   method indexOf(int)
   location: variable COMPONENT_IDS of type int[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array's don't have indexOf method

Use [List's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) indexOf method

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(COMPONENT_IDS).indexOf(i);
```

You need to convert the array to list using [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class

Comment: mm i don't like it, making a new data structure only for index

Comment: see my answer, only need to change the loop

Comment: `Arrays.asList` only creates one object; it's constant-time.

Comment: A single call to `Arrays.asList` is constant time.  The `indexOf` call will be more expensive, but there's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 3):

Just change your loop to old fashioned way

```
for(int index=0; index < COMPONENT_IDS.length ; index ++){
     //your code here 
      . 
      if(COMPONENT_IDS[index] == c) { 
     answer.equals(COMPONENT_STRINGS[index]);
      .
      .
}
```